# Figuring out an expression to evaluate a loop

Tags: c++

this is a broad question, with a specific example. My question is, how do you figure out how to evaluate an algorithm or expression in a loop?

In the example beblow, I figured out how to use a loop to calculate a square root using a counter with the babylonian algorithm and it appears to be working ok.

But I can't figure out how evaluate this to a certain degree, say within .01 without using a counter.  I see other people on the web doing it without a counter but the abililty to do it eludes me.

Here is my counter version:

```
int count(20);

    while (count > 0 )
{
    if (guess <= (guess * p) + guess)
        prevGuess = guess;
    else
        r = input / guess;

    guess = (guess + r) / 2.0;
    count -= 1;
    cout << "\nGuess = " << guess;
}
```

I've tried doing things like:

```
while ((guess - lastGuess) / lastGuess)
```

and

```
while(guess - lastGuess * .01)
```

But I either get just one interation or an infinite loop.

What is a good method to figure how to evaluate any algorithm inside a loop?

And I don't mean just for this little program, I mean for anything, even something like x + y = 2.

Would you do something like:

```
while(x + y !=2) {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So your question is how do you write a loop so it runs until a specific expression is true/false?

Comment: Avoid to compare for equality with floating point.

Comment: @ahjohnston25 yes, basically, thanks

Comment: what is actually your question? what do you mean with x+y=2? `while(x + y !=2) {}` is in most cases just an infinite loop but I would not call it algorithm... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I find it hard to understand your code snippet. none of your variables is declared or initialised. It is not clear, what is p,r and input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare your error to your determined error limit, instead of zero as your attempts do.

You would use

```
 while (abs((guess - lastGuess) / lastGuess) > .01)
```

for a relative error of .01, and

```
while(abs(guess - lastGuess) > .01)
```

for an absolute one.

Comment: would you update the variables in the loop like :  r = input / guess;
  guess = (guess + r) / 2; lastGuess = guess;

Comment: how did you figure that out?  Looking at the algorithm, how did you know to evaluate it using (guess - lastGuess) / lastGuess > .01? Thanks

Comment: @999cm999 Almost - you must save the old guess (`lastGuess = guess;`) before you calculate the new one.

Comment: @999cm999 I paid attention in class. ;-) (It's actually not quite the error, but a measure of how much the value has changed since last, and only works with converging series.) And now somebody's going to tell me how wrong I am...

Answer (score 2):

Normally this kind of computation can stop when the next iteration doesn't change the value by much; for example

```
for(;;) {
    double next_v = (v + (n / v)) / 2;
    if (fabs(v - next_v) < eps) break; // We got there
    v = next_v;
}
```

where `eps` is the accuracy you want in the result.

Answer (score 1):

In while (and every loop) there is condition which tells program when to stop it. This conditions must be some expression which return true or false value. Simpler, it's just an equation, or something which gives as clear answer: true or false. In your example expression like : `((guess - lastGuess) / lastGuess)` isn't returning either true nor false. It returns some numbers etc.
Expression like `((guess - lastGuess) / lastGuess) == 4` will return true if `((guess - lastGuess) / lastGuess)` will be equal to 4 and false if not. This example will work: `while(x + y !=2)`. Program will call loop until x+y is equal 2.